# How does linux route to an IP address from the routable subnet if the IP address is assigned to a virtual interface on multiple nodes

Tags: linux, networking, ip, routing

I see a scenario working that I do not understand (bad luck, I know).

I have a cluster comprising 3 nodes, each of them has a NIC (ens4) with an individual IP address assigned, e.g. 10.10.20.210. The IP addresses of all nodes belong to the same subnet, e.g. 10.10.20.0/24.

On all 3 nodes, I have a virtual NIC (kube-ipvs0) with an address assigned, e.g. 10.10.20.205) that belongs to the same routable subnet 10.10.20.0/24.

```
3: ens4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fa:16:3e:7b:f8:9c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.10.20.210/24 brd 10.10.20.255 scope global dynamic ens4
       valid_lft 86112sec preferred_lft 86112sec
    inet6 fe80::f816:3eff:fe7b:f89c/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

6: kube-ipvs0: <BROADCAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default
    link/ether 7e:49:81:e2:bb:f7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
        inet 10.10.20.205/32 scope global kube-ipvs0
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

There is no route advertisement via BGP done for the virtual IP address / subnet (as it belongs to a routable subnet).

I can reach the virtual IP address without knowing via which node (every node runs kube-proxy / IPVS that DNATs the virtual IP to the destination / pod IP), and based on what routing mechanism / information (there is NOARP set on the virtual NIC). I am using Ubuntu 20.04.

I have few questions:
How does the routing work? (any tables to inspect and share here?)
Is this a valid routing scenario?

Background: The idea is to avoid the use of a real virtual subnet and the associated route advertisement, e.g. using BGP.

Best,
Richard

Comment: Are you sure ARP isn't being used? By default Linux will (somewhat unusually) answer to ARP queries for addresses that belong to other interfaces, and the NOARP flag only applies to traffic that would go through the kube-ipvs0 interface itself; it doesn't prevent other interfaces that _do_ use ARP from responding for this interface's address (e.g. when ens4 receives an ARP query for 10.10.20.205).

Comment: @user1686, thanks for your reply. Yes, this makes sense, i.e. it may work because of the settings:
`net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_ignore
net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_announce`

I will check this and update the post.

Comment: Yes, specifically, does a packet capture or an `arping` test show replies from this address, and does it stop working if the hosts have `arp_ignore` set to a non-zero value (arp_announce is irrelevant)?

Comment: @user1686 while checking it, is this considered a valid routing setup? To me it looks like all nodes will send responses to ARP because the IP address 10.10.20.205 is on the kube-proxy vNIC of all nodes and the first ARP responses will "win"?

Comment: If they all have an identical IP address, then yeah it should behave like a duplicate IP where the most recent ARP response gets the traffic. Check the local ARP table and see which mac address shows up for that IP. Whether that's valid or not depends on if you care which node you connect to

Comment: With IPVS being involved, I have no idea how that affects the situation. Normally, I would be somewhat worried of a client's or router's ARP cache entry expiring while connections are still live (shouldn't happen during traffic but might happen if connections stay idle) and another server's ARP response being picked up instead, cutting the connections. I've done something like this for two gateways, but generally either something like VRRP/CARP to assign a shared address in a more deterministic way or routing an off-subnet address to the server with BGP/OSPF might be a better solution.

Comment: @user1686 thanks again. I hereby confirm that it works as you have suggested. The ARP to an IP assigned on a virtual NIC is answered if net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_ignore is set to 0. If set to 1, there is no answer to ARP. Also your last comment is very helpful. I very much appreciate your help!